# How to set CallBack in Kotlin?

Tags: android, google-maps, callback, geolocation, kotlin

I try to transfer device geolocation into fragment and using callback. But after set one time link is null

```
 fun updateLocation(location:LatLng){
   Log.d(TAG,"Update fragment "+ localUpdater+" "+location)
   localUpdater?.tryOutLocation(location)

 }
 private inner class Receiver: BroadcastReceiver(){
     override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
         val bundle = intent?.extras!![AppConstants.LOCATION_BUNDLE] as Bundle
         val location = bundle.get(AppConstants.LOCATION_BUNDLE) as LatLng
         updateLocation(location)                  
     }
 }

fun setUpdater(updater: IUpdateLocation){
    this.localUpdater = updater
    Log.d(TAG,"Update fragment1 "+localUpdater)
}
```

I declare callback:

```
private var localUpdater: IUpdateLocation? = null
```

Code interface:

```
interface IUpdateLocation {
    fun tryOutLocation(location:LatLng)
}
```

Fragment code:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    act?.setUpdater(this)
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
}


override fun tryOutLocation(location: LatLng) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Update fragment map fragment "+location+" ")
    if(gMap != null){
        gMap?.uiSettings?.isZoomGesturesEnabled
        gMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Test"))
        gMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 20.0f))
}
```

First time [callback is set and work (log)](http://prntscr.com/fzsd36)

but after first calling link is null. Why? How I can fix this problem?

Comment: well if it works the first time that means that its not entering the onReceive method the second time and its not calling the updateLocation method. Which means that you are not sending a broadcast the right way. I'm guessing that you didnt put it in the onResume method because onCreate gets called only once thats why it works only the first time. I'm just guessing here :)

Comment: What is `act`? Did you ensure that `act` is not null in `onActivityCreated`?

Comment: which `link` are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I found where was mistake. I am using parent BaseActivity where is inner class Receiver. In SplashActivity that Inherited from BaseActivity I created object Receiver, and callback I created from fragment in MainActivity inherited from BaseActivity too. I had situation when first setting callback and after that was creating Reciever. I endured all processes in MainActivity and it work.